# Transistor-level Verilog module for a CMOS 3-input XNOR gate

Tags: verilog

How to write a transistor-level Verilog module for a CMOS 3-input
XNOR gate: XNOR-3 using CMOS and PMOS transistor with 3 input gate.

Answer (score 0):

You would use structural Verilog. For example,

```
module xnor3(a, b, c, y)
    // instantiate a NMOS
    nmos n1(.D(...), .S(...), .G(...))

    // other modules
endmodule
```

This would require that you have a NMOS and PMOS module in your library. If you specify the tool you are working with, then I can help you add the transistors to your library if you don't already have them.